# what is the data I should write in config.xml of an android app using ibm watson chatbot?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson

I am an android developer. I am trying to use IBM chatbot in my android app. I am following this tutorial

> https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/android-watson-chatbot.html#configure_run_android_app

I am beginner at IBM watson I don't unserstand I should write in config.xml . I am very confused of that and I tried to search a lot for a thing that explains that but I didn't find.

this is the config.xml code :

```
<resources>
<!-- Watson Conversation Service Credentials -->
<string name="workspace_id">/string>
<string name="conversation_username"></string>
<string name="conversation_password"></string>

<!--Watson Speech-To-Text Service Credentials-->
<string name="STT_username"></string>
<string name="STT_password"></string>

<!--Watson Text-To-Speech Service Credentials-->
<string name="TTS_username"></string>
<string name="TTS_password"></string>
```

I want to know what is the things that I needs to write and how can I get it from the website. I can't understand what is the required data well

Comment: did you really read the link you provided ? the explanation is given in PLAIN TEXT

Comment: @LoneWanderer I can't find these data in the service credentials

Answer (score 0):

I think that what will be confusing you is that the .xml file has place holders for username and password credentials, and if you have created new instances of the services you will be seeing an IAM Key as credentials in the steps that go

> Go to the IBM Cloud Catalog and select Watson Assistant service > Lite
> plan under Watson. Click Create.
>
> Click Service credentials on the left
> pane and click New credential to add a new credential.
>
> Click View
> Credentials to see the credentials. Save the credentials in a text
> editor for quick reference.

So the question becomes - Has the sample app that you are using been tested/updated with IAM Keys? You should raise a ticket against the GitHub repo that you were asked to clone.

Comment: The app uses these old things in the manifest. And how can I get the workSpaceId ?

Comment: If the app uses username / password and the only credentials that you have are IAM then the app is broken. The instructions should show you how to get a Workspace ID. You can use the API to list workspaces, or you can use the Assistant Workspace tooling, which will be the same tooling that your use to import the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create three [AI services](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/?category=ai)

- Watson Assistant
- Speech to Text
- Text to Speech

Once you create these services (under [Dashboard](https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard/apps)), click on each service to see **Service credentials** on the left pane. Click on View Credential or create a new credential.

Pass the credentials (username or password) as shown below

> ```
> <string name="conversation_username">abcsld-1jdfjdf-jnhjh</string>
> ```